# Работа с нескольки таблицами в одной БД в room

Tags: java, android, android-room

подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом привязать более 1 таблицы к бд и работать с ними?

Код Database:

```
@androidx.room.Database(entities = {Apiary.class, Fam.class}, version = 1) //предположил, что сюда ее нужно добавить
    public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract DBDao DBDao();
    }
```

2 таблицы:

```
@Entity
public class Fam {
@PrimaryKey
public long id;
public long number;
public String type;
public long date_add;
public String poroda;
public long matka_year;

}
```

и

```
@Entity
public class Apiary {
    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public long kol_fams;
}
```

Dao:

```
@androidx.room.Dao
public interface DBDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Apiary")
    List<Apiary> getAllfromApiary();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insert_apiary(Apiary ap);

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    void insert_fam(Fam fam); //сделал так, но сомневаюсь, что будет работать

    @Update
    void update_apiary(Apiary ap);

    @Update
    void update_fam(Fam fam); // и тут

    @Delete
    void delete(Apiary ap);
}
```

Изначально в бд было только Apiary, сейчас появилась необходимость добавить еще 1 таблицу, подскажите, как поступить с Dao, надо ли что-то дополнительное прописывать или так как сделал я будет работать? Проверить не могу, т.к. пока нет возможности для этого (работаю), заранее прошу прощения за возможно глупый вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

@StudyAndroid!

Если Ваши таблицы в БД не будут зависеть друг от друга, то Вам необходимо лишь добавить еще:

- один [`AnotherItemDao`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#dao)
- один [`AnotherItemEntiry`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room#data-entity)
- добавить `AnotherItemDao` в `AppDatabase`

> подскажите, как поступить с Dao, надо ли что-то дополнительное прописывать

У каждой таблицы свой Dao. Да, нужно будет создать еще один Dao для новой таблицы.

Для зависимых друг от друга таблиц ([Реляционная база данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)) следует ознакомиться со [статьей](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships).

Удачи Вам!